# Instagram - Limit on returning users like

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Has anyone already bunped in a limit for the returns of likes a given user has made?

For example, I know that when you pull the list of likes a media has received you only get a total of 120. I want to know if the same occurs to a User.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the *undocumented* `count` parameter to a large number there would be no such limits as 120.